# Ionic/Cordova FCM: Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

Since I installed this [Native FCM Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/) in Ionic Project I'm always getting the following Error when im executing `ionic cordova android build`:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.046 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

My Ionic Info:

```
cli packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.1.3
    npm  : 4.6.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Here is my snippet of **/platform/android/project.properties** file:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/bar-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/bar-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/bar-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle
```

Here is the snippet of my **/platform/android/build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

**What have I tried?**
If I'm changing all Verisons to `9.0.0` in **build.gradle** and **project.properties** I'm getting this error:

```
Total time: 12.661 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseException;
```

If you need something more please tell me and I'll add it!

Comment: have you tried the version 9 for play-services-base and ads, since that is what the error says `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.`

Comment: yes I already tried to change all versions to `9.0.0` but it didnt work either.

Comment: did it still said the same error ? in that case you need to delete those binaries and then reinstall those

Comment: Updated my Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [my answer](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/332#issuecomment-363368603)

Just edit:

/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm/blabla-FCMPlugin.gradle

add google() to repositories{}

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

and same for /platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/blabla-build.gradle

Also I've used script ([gms-gradle-fix.zip](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/files/1698510/gms-gradle-fix.zip)) and in config.xml under:

`<platform name="android">
         ...
        <hook src="scripts/gms-gradle-fix.js" type="before_prepare" />`

Comment: ill try it out! Will mark it as Solution then if it worked!

Comment: For me is also helped to open up project in android studio. Than I fix issues with gradle 4.4 version updates and better understand version dependencies

Comment: ill try that too this weekend and then ill post the result. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I tried the solution but it didn't work, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all versions are the same.

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/bar-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/bar-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/bar-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
```

And then add the bottom line com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0